# Почему $watch не всегда срабатывает при изменении объекта?

Tags: angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.select']);

app.decorator('uiSelectMatchDirective', function($rootScope, $delegate) {
  var originalLinkFn = $delegate[0].link;
  $delegate[0].compile = function(element) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs, controller) {
      elm.bind('click', function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('customSelect', scope.$selectMultiple.activeMatchIndex);
      });
      originalLinkFn.apply($delegate, arguments);
    };
  };
  return $delegate;
});

app.decorator('uiSelectMultipleDirective', function($delegate) {
  var originalLinkFn = $delegate[0].link;
  $delegate[0].compile = function(element) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs, controller) {
      scope.$on('uis:select', function(event, item) {
        scope.$selectMultiple.activeMatchIndex = controller[0].selected.length;
      });
      originalLinkFn.apply($delegate, arguments);
    };
  };
  return $delegate;
});

app.controller('detailsController', function($scope, toolService) {
    $scope.assembly = {
      tools: []
    };

    $scope.$on('customSelect', function(event, value) {
      $scope.tool = $scope.assembly.tools[value];
      console.log('from handler custom select');
    });

    $scope.$watch('tool', function(value) {
      console.log('from watch')
    });

    $scope.onSelectTool = function(tool) {
      $scope.tool = $scope.assembly.tools[$scope.assembly.tools.indexOf(tool)];
    };
  $scope.tools = toolService.getTools();
});

app.factory('assemblyService', function() {
  var assemblies = [{
      "Position": 1.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 104,
          "Type": "Центровочное сверло D10 ∠90°",
          "OrderCode": "D5306100",
          "Vendor": "YG-1",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 40.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 200.00,
        },
        {
          "Id": 53,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "50 10 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 40.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 200.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 1.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 5.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 889,
          "Type": "Корпус фрезы D42 z5",
          "OrderCode": "5 42 367",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 43.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 2,
          "AmountPlates": 5,
          "Durability": 90.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 750,
          "Type": "Пластина r2",
          "OrderCode": "04 67 896 R20 M40",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 12,
          "Overhang": 43.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 2,
          "AmountPlates": 5,
          "Durability": 90.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 890,
          "Type": "Патрон ",
          "OrderCode": "HSK 63-16-50",
          "Vendor": "KEMMLER",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 43.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 2,
          "AmountPlates": 5,
          "Durability": 90.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 40.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 9.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 891,
          "Type": "Фреза D20 r1",
          "OrderCode": "ф20R1z4 nACRo ТП",
          "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 70.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 223,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "60 20 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 70.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 6.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 11.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 1241,
          "Type": "Фреза D12 r2",
          "OrderCode": "ф12R2z4 nACRo ТП",
          "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 55.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 51,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "50 12 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 55.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 40.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 15.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 547,
          "Type": "Сверло D5.60",
          "OrderCode": "DH451056",
          "Vendor": "YG-1",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 25.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 100.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 78,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "50 06 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 25.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 100.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 3.00,
      "Note": null
    }
  ];
  return {
    getAssemblies: () => {
      return assemblies.slice();
    }
  };
});

app.factory('toolService', function() {
  var tools = [{
      "Id": 104,
      "Type": "Центровочное сверло D10 ∠90°",
      "OrderCode": "D5306100",
      "Vendor": "YG-1",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 53,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "50 10 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 889,
      "Type": "Корпус фрезы D42 z5",
      "OrderCode": "5 42 367",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 750,
      "Type": "Пластина r2",
      "OrderCode": "04 67 896 R20 M40",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 890,
      "Type": "Патрон ",
      "OrderCode": "HSK 63-16-50",
      "Vendor": "KEMMLER",
      "IsConsumables": false,
    },
    {
      "Id": 891,
      "Type": "Фреза D20 r1",
      "OrderCode": "ф20R1z4 nACRo ТП",
      "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 223,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "60 20 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 1241,
      "Type": "Фреза D12 r2",
      "OrderCode": "ф12R2z4 nACRo ТП",
      "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 51,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "50 12 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 547,
      "Type": "Сверло D5.60",
      "OrderCode": "DH451056",
      "Vendor": "YG-1",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 78,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "50 06 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    }
  ];
  return {
    getTools: () => {
      return tools.slice();
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.19.4/select.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.19.4/select.min.js"></script>

  <div class="panel panel-default"  ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="detailsController">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Инструмент</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <ui-select multiple ng-model="assembly.tools" limit="100" on-select="onSelectTool($item)">
              <ui-select-match placeholder="Введите строку для поиска">{{$item.OrderCode}}</ui-select-match>
              <ui-select-choices repeat="tool in (tools| filter:$select.search | limitTo:$select.limit)">
                <span ng-bind="tool.OrderCode"></span>
                <p class="small" ng-bind="tool.Type"></p>
              </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Кол-во режущих граней</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.AmountCuttingEdge" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Кол-во пластин</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.AmountPlates" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Вылет</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.Overhang" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Стойкость</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.Durability" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

В исходную директиву при помощи декоратора внесены незначительные изменения(создание события).

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('customSelect', scope.$selectMultiple.activeMatchIndex);
```

В контроллере обрабатываю это событие

```
$scope.$on('customSelect', function(event, value){
     console.log('from custom select');
     $scope.tool = $scope.assembly.tools[value];
});
```

так же в контроллере слежу за изменением `tool` при помощи `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('tool', function(value){
    console.log('from watch');
});
```

Выбираем любое кол-во инструментов в выпадающем списке, каждая добавленная позиция становится активной, применение класса `btn-primary` из бутстрапа.

При первом клике по одной из выбранных позиций в консоле видно что сработал обработчик события `customSelect` который в свою очередь *меняет* `$scope.tool`, но почему то не срабатывает обработчик из `$watch`, а если повторно кликнуть тот же элемент то в консоли видно что сработало оба обработчика.

Подскажите почему так происходит.

Comment: В коде не удается отловить событие customSelect в контроллере (т.е. ни один console.log не выводится из тела функции внутри $on("cistomSelect").Это я попытался запустить ваш код в снипете. Есть одна догадка, что возможно разные скоупы в момент первой инциализации ($rootScope и $scope и scope внутри функции).

Comment: @alexoander, сниппет на текущий момент рабочий, попробуйте запустить на выполнение сейчас

Comment: @Bald попробуйте после строки `$scope.tool = $scope.assembly.tools[value];` вызвать `$scope.$apply();` как выше указали может из-за разных скоупов по разному работает `$watch` и поэтому он не вызывается.

Comment: @MrFylypenko вылазиет ошибка, что в принципе ожидаемо, `$apply` же в данном случае не нужен. обратите внимание что если *кликнуть* по тому же элементу второй раз, то все срабатывает

Comment: @Bald интересно что за ошибка? Вы не совсем поняли порядок срабатывания событий, сейчас я создаю 1 объект (D5306100), указываю в нем 5 ед., создаю 2 объект (50 10 A63 S), указываю 2ед., кликаю на первый объект, осталось 2ед. но должно показываться 5ед. В консоли должно выводиться  $on('customSelect') затем вотч, но не наоборот. Происходит "запаздывания" вотча, что неправильно и `$apply` должен решить эту проблему.

Comment: @MrFylypenko хм, я вроде пробовал *обновление* делать внутри `$apply`. Опубликуйте ответ, я его приму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в декораторе.

Если глянуть в [исходники того же `ngClick`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c8d349870812284a82896087c05c2d19c8f5cdfd/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L62), можно отметить, что *внутри* обработчика jqLite вызывается `$evalAsync`, либо `$apply`.

В твоем случае ты делаешь [`$broadcast`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/817ac56719505680ac4c9997972e8f39eb40a6d0/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1272), который, как видно из исходников *не* запускает `$digest`, следовательно нет проверки `watch`

Поэтому его нужно запускать самому, например с помощью `.$apply()`.

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.select']);

app.decorator('uiSelectMatchDirective', function($rootScope, $delegate) {
  var originalLinkFn = $delegate[0].link;
  $delegate[0].compile = function(element) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs, controller) {
      elm.on('click', function(e) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('customSelect', scope.$selectMultiple.activeMatchIndex);
        scope.$apply();
      });
      originalLinkFn.apply($delegate, arguments);
    };
  };
  return $delegate;
});

app.decorator('uiSelectMultipleDirective', function($delegate) {
  var originalLinkFn = $delegate[0].link;
  $delegate[0].compile = function(element) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs, controller) {
      scope.$on('uis:select', function(event, item) {
        scope.$selectMultiple.activeMatchIndex = controller[0].selected.length;
      });
      originalLinkFn.apply($delegate, arguments);
    };
  };
  return $delegate;
});

app.controller('detailsController', function($scope, toolService) {
  $scope.assembly = {
    tools: []
  };

  $scope.$on('customSelect', function(event, value) {
    $scope.tool = $scope.assembly.tools[value];
    console.log('from handler custom select');
  });

  $scope.$watch('tool', function(value) {
    console.log('from watch')
  });

  $scope.onSelectTool = function(tool) {
    $scope.tool = $scope.assembly.tools[$scope.assembly.tools.indexOf(tool)];
  };
  $scope.tools = toolService.getTools();
});

app.factory('assemblyService', function() {
  var assemblies = [{
      "Position": 1.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 104,
          "Type": "Центровочное сверло D10 ∠90°",
          "OrderCode": "D5306100",
          "Vendor": "YG-1",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 40.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 200.00,
        },
        {
          "Id": 53,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "50 10 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 40.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 200.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 1.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 5.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 889,
          "Type": "Корпус фрезы D42 z5",
          "OrderCode": "5 42 367",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 43.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 2,
          "AmountPlates": 5,
          "Durability": 90.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 750,
          "Type": "Пластина r2",
          "OrderCode": "04 67 896 R20 M40",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 12,
          "Overhang": 43.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 2,
          "AmountPlates": 5,
          "Durability": 90.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 890,
          "Type": "Патрон ",
          "OrderCode": "HSK 63-16-50",
          "Vendor": "KEMMLER",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 43.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 2,
          "AmountPlates": 5,
          "Durability": 90.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 40.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 9.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 891,
          "Type": "Фреза D20 r1",
          "OrderCode": "ф20R1z4 nACRo ТП",
          "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 70.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 223,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "60 20 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 70.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 6.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 11.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 1241,
          "Type": "Фреза D12 r2",
          "OrderCode": "ф12R2z4 nACRo ТП",
          "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 55.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 51,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "50 12 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 55.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 180.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 40.00,
      "Note": null
    },
    {
      "Position": 15.00,
      "Tools": [{
          "Id": 547,
          "Type": "Сверло D5.60",
          "OrderCode": "DH451056",
          "Vendor": "YG-1",
          "IsConsumables": true,
          "Sequance": 14,
          "Overhang": 25.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 100.00
        },
        {
          "Id": 78,
          "Type": "Термопатрон ",
          "OrderCode": "50 06 A63 S",
          "Vendor": "POKOLM",
          "IsConsumables": false,
          "Sequance": 6,
          "Overhang": 25.00,
          "AmountCuttingEdge": 0,
          "AmountPlates": 0,
          "Durability": 100.00
        }
      ],
      "Runtime": 3.00,
      "Note": null
    }
  ];
  return {
    getAssemblies: () => {
      return assemblies.slice();
    }
  };
});

app.factory('toolService', function() {
  var tools = [{
      "Id": 104,
      "Type": "Центровочное сверло D10 ∠90°",
      "OrderCode": "D5306100",
      "Vendor": "YG-1",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 53,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "50 10 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 889,
      "Type": "Корпус фрезы D42 z5",
      "OrderCode": "5 42 367",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 750,
      "Type": "Пластина r2",
      "OrderCode": "04 67 896 R20 M40",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 890,
      "Type": "Патрон ",
      "OrderCode": "HSK 63-16-50",
      "Vendor": "KEMMLER",
      "IsConsumables": false,
    },
    {
      "Id": 891,
      "Type": "Фреза D20 r1",
      "OrderCode": "ф20R1z4 nACRo ТП",
      "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 223,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "60 20 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 1241,
      "Type": "Фреза D12 r2",
      "OrderCode": "ф12R2z4 nACRo ТП",
      "Vendor": "ТЕХНОПОЛИС",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 51,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "50 12 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    },
    {
      "Id": 547,
      "Type": "Сверло D5.60",
      "OrderCode": "DH451056",
      "Vendor": "YG-1",
      "IsConsumables": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 78,
      "Type": "Термопатрон ",
      "OrderCode": "50 06 A63 S",
      "Vendor": "POKOLM",
      "IsConsumables": false
    }
  ];
  return {
    getTools: () => {
      return tools.slice();
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.19.4/select.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.19.4/select.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default" ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="detailsController">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Инструмент</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <ui-select multiple ng-model="assembly.tools" limit="100" on-select="onSelectTool($item)">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Введите строку для поиска">{{$item.OrderCode}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="tool in (tools| filter:$select.search | limitTo:$select.limit)">
              <span ng-bind="tool.OrderCode"></span>
              <p class="small" ng-bind="tool.Type"></p>
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Кол-во режущих граней</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.AmountCuttingEdge" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Кол-во пластин</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.AmountPlates" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Вылет</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.Overhang" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Стойкость</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tool.Durability" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему это срабатывает при последующих переключениях: внутри элемента с классом `ui-select-match` есть элемент с классом `ui-select-match-item` - у которого прописан `ng-click`.

Таким образом при клике, сначала вызывается клик внутреннего элемента, проходит digest цикл, затем шлется твой broadcast и на этом все заканчивается.
При следующем клике при проверке `watch` определяет, что `tools` изменился с предыдущего запуска digest - и отрисовывает, а затем в обработчике твоего события ты снова меняешь реальное значение tools.